# How can I test if a COM type is registered?

Tags: c#, com, registration

Say I've got a load of COM types and I'd like to check if a particular type has been registered. I can use Activator.CreateInstance to actually try and create the class, but I was wondering if there's a simpler way actually check in advance if the class is actually registered.

I'd prefer not to go to the registry directly - I'm looking for something easy to use like the Activator.CreateInstance call above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB. [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) doesn't directly create COM class instance, it requires an interop assembly to have been generated and installed (e.g. by `tlbimp.exe`)—but this makes no difference here.

The simplest way to check without reading the registry is to try creating an instance and catch the possible exceptions due to the type not being available. (E.g. `COMException` if the underlying component is not installed correctly, `TypeLoadException` (IIRC) if the interop assembly is missing.)

Comment: Good point - my understanding of how the COM interop works is pretty basic. Thanks for the answer though - it's how I would have naively done it. 

Out of interest, would the registry way not be a pain if you have to deal with 32\64 bit issues?

Comment: @cristobalito there are potentially a lot of places to check, by restricting to inproc cases you can reduce it to `HKCR:\CLID\<clsid>\InProcServer32` and `HKCU:\Software\Classes\CLSID\<clsid>\InProcServer32` (registry path remapping will handle the 32/64bit issue for you).

Comment: If you go for the registry solution you need to take care of "reg free COM" also.